# windows task scheduler doesn't open web browser

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, administrator

My task runs a .bat file that contain a action that run some .jar file.
When I run manually the .bat file the .jar works perfectly and open a web browser .
But when I ran the .bat file from the task(right click on task->run), the task runs with out opening the browser.

I cant find out if the problem is in the java code or in the task itself.

java:

```
 Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

It worked in the past and now its not working any more.
OS: xp
task run as nt administrator/system.
Thank you.

Comment: My guess is it doesn't work because the System account may not have access to the desktop. Try running the task as your own user.

Comment: Can't you directly open a browser from the batch file? Please show us some more code.

Comment: There is no more code to show...the rest is just plain java that collect and process data. how do i run as my user?

Comment: doen any one have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

It appears you are on Windows XP? Have you tried these solutions to open the browser window?

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://some.web.site.com

-or-

explorer http://some.web.site.com

Comment: sorry, this isn't an answer, please move it to the comments section above if I can't find it first.